# Swift add calendar event

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, eventkit

I am looking to add an event to the calendar app though Xcode. I watched a tutorial that was for Swift 1, however I am working in Swift 2 and am having a bit of trouble. This is the code I currently have:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

// 2
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) {
case .Authorized:
    insertEvent(eventStore)
case .Denied:
    print("Access denied")
case .NotDetermined:
    // 3
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion:
        {[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if granted {
                self!.insertEvent(eventStore)
            } else {
                print("Access denied")
            }
        })
default:
    print("Case Default")
}
```

My error come on this line:

```
{[weak self] (granted: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // 2
    switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) {
    case .Authorized:
        insertEvent(eventStore)
    case .Denied:
        print("Access denied")
    case .NotDetermined:
        // 3
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { [weak self](granted, error) in
            if granted {
                self?.insertEvent(eventStore)
            } else {
                print("Access denied")
            }
        })

    default:
        print("Case Default")
    }
```

The error should be `NSError?` type not `NSError!`.